# ¿como mostrar una imagen a modo de error de conexion en un webview kotlin?

Tags: android, android-studio

quisiera mostrar una imagen a modo de error de conexión, porque la que trae por defecto en el `Webview` queda feo.

lo he intentado pero solamente funciona si giro el dispositivo, que estoy haciendo mal?

Android Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Codigo:

// verificacion de conexion a internet

```
    val connectivityManager =
        getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
    val networkInfo = connectivityManager.activeNetworkInfo

    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected) {
        // Si hay conexión a Internet en este momento

        webView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        imageView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        boton1.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        boton2.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        boton3.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        textView.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        imageView2.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        boton4.visibility = View.INVISIBLE



    } else {
        // No hay conexión a Internet en este momento
        webView.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        imageView.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        boton1.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        boton2.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        boton3.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        textView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        imageView2.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        boton4.visibility = View.VISIBLE

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

En este caso te sugiero agregues el código en onResume() que de acuerdo al ciclo de vida  de la `Activity`, se llama cuando la actividad entra en el estado "reanudado", pasa a primer plano.

```
override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
    // Agrega tu código aquí para validar conexión.
 }
```

De esta forma se realizará la validación al iniciar la `Activity`.